# Creating object(s) within a Class

Tags: c++, class, arduino, libraries

I have this problem:

**Problem:**

- I am trying to create a library (ard33WiFi) that manages and handles
  a couple of other libraries (WiFiServer library for example)
- I need to create  the server object that I then use in functions in my Library (ard33WiFi):

`WiFiServer myServer(iPort);`

- The problem is that when I call myServer in the members of the class I get:

`'myServer' was not declared in this scope`

**Where/how** do I declare myServer so that is becomes available to the entire class (ard33WiFi)? I have taken out any decleration because whatever I was trying was wrong. I have pasted a skeleton code below.

```
// HEADER FILE (.h)
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#ifndef Ard33WiFi_h
#define Ard33WiFi_h

#include <WiFiNINA.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>

class ard33WiFi{
  public:
    ard33WiFi(int iPort)

    void someFunction();
    void serverBegin();

  private:
    int _iPort;

};
#endif

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// C++ FILE (.cpp)
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <Ard33Wifi.h>

ard33WiFi::ard33WiFi(int iPort){
  _iPort = iPort;
}
void ard33WiFi::someFunction(){
  // code here required to prepare the server for initializing
  // but ultimately not relevant to the question
}
void ard33WiFi::serverBegin(){
  myServer.begin();
  Serial.println("Server Online");
}
```

I run into the same problem with the UDP library as I need to call the UDP object in various functions to do UDP things.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't see `WiFiServer myServer(iPort);` inside the code you provided. All I see is `myServer` which is not declared as the error indicates.

Comment: Put `WiFiServer myServer;` after `int _iPort;` . And use your `ard33WiFi`'s initializer list to initailze the port

Comment: That is why you need to initialize in the constructor's initializer list. thankfully it has the port that you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you are using this:

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/WiFiServer

I can see that you are not declaring the myServer in your class; that I guess is the error in your code. If I am not wrong, it should be something like this:

```cpp
#ifndef Ard33WiFi_h
#define Ard33WiFi_h

#include <WiFiNINA.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>
#include <WiFi.h>  // Not sure if you have to append this include

class ard33WiFi{
  public:
    ard33WiFi(int iPort)

    void someFunction();
    void serverBegin();

  private:
    int _iPort;
    WiFiServer myServer;

};
#endif
```

The implementation, you would need to initialise the instance:

```cpp
#include <Ard33Wifi.h>

ard33WiFi::ard33WiFi(int iPort):myServer(iPort), _iPort(iPort) {
}

void ard33WiFi::someFunction(){
  // code here required to prepare the server for initializing
  // but ultimately not relevant to the question
}
void ard33WiFi::serverBegin(){
  myServer.begin();
  Serial.println("Server Online");
}
```

---

Comment: Note that members are initialized in the iorder that they are defined, so `myServer(iPort), _iPort(iPort)` initializes `_iPort` first even through it is in the list second. It doesn't matter a bit here, but it's good thing to remember because it can cause some subtle <expletive deleted> ups when it does matter.

Comment: @alejandro. Thank you for your answer. As mentioned in my problem brief I deliberately left the deceleration of myServer out because where ever I tried putting it was wrong. Regarding you answer. That looks very different from any declaration I've tried and I will try that later today. Thank you very much. I'll keep you posted if it worked.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I will have to do some more research into the initializing of the constructor. If you have any great links for good info regarding the syntax behind this step? ard33WiFi::ard33WiFi(int iPort):myServer(iPort), _iPort(iPort)

Comment: The link above show an example, maybe that could help you, I paste here the link again just to clarify: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/WiFiServer